# Integrate Outlook and Netsuite on custom record

Tags: outlook, netsuite

We would like to link our outgoing and incoming email into Netsuite on a CUSTOM record.
Found Cloudextent, however seems only to save on CRM records (i.e. Leads etc). Any idea for (alternative) solution?

Answer (score 0):

The NetSuite for Outlook bundle was no longer supported by Oracle after June 30, 2019.  They suggest using third party apps.  (Ref [Suite Answer 83899](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/83899/kw/83899)) If you have access in NetSuite to SuiteApp Marketplace, definitely search there.  I've only heard of CloudExtend and SuperSync - Outlook Integration; but don't have first hand experience with either.

There's [this CloudExtend enhancement](https://ideas-ceol.cloudextend.io/c/30-create-additional-netsuite-record-types-directly-from-outlook) that suggests that accessing Custom Record types was made available as of CloudExtend Outlook for NetSuite version 3.3.0.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have done some investigation and reached out to cloutextend. This seems a nice integration. Only issue is that they have fixed record types, custom records is not yet on the backlog/roadmap. However cases is one of the record type and we will tweak cases in order to get what I want.

Comment: Oh I see.  Best of luck!